# ngModel not loading value dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

So I have this json returning from spring service as "etapaData" variable.

```
0:
id: 266
aplicacao: {id: 192, nome: "Sistema de Cadastro", checked: false}
erro: {id: 220, nome: "Falta de orçamento", checked: false}
perfil: {id: 8, nome: "Usuario", checked: false}
checked: true
ordem: 1
tarefas: [{…}]
__proto__: Object
1:
id: 267
aplicacao: {id: 204, nome: "Sistema Financeiro", checked: false}
erro: {id: 237, nome: "Número de licenças excedidas", checked: false}
perfil: {id: 188, nome: "Administrador", checked: false}
checked: true
ordem: 2
tarefas: [{…}]
__proto__: Object
2:
id: 269
aplicacao: {id: 204, nome: "Sistema Financeiro", checked: false}
erro: {id: 221, nome: "Nullpointer Exception", checked: false}
perfil: {id: 10, nome: "N2", checked: false}
checked: true
ordem: 3
tarefas: (2) [{…}, {…}]
__proto__: Object
length: 3
```

when displaying it in the hml, the "ordem" value is not loading properly, all the three elements are being populated as the last one from the list with value "3":

[image]

They should be like "1","2" and "3".

This is the html code:

```
<div class="container" style="padding-left: 60px;">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h1>Atualizar Workflow</h1>

        <div [hidden]="submitted">
            <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                <h4>Nome</h4>  
                <div class="input-field col s6">                    
                    <input placeholder="Digite o nome do Workflow" type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" required [(ngModel)]="workflow.nome"
                        name="nome">
                </div>
                <h4>Etapas</h4>                
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Check</th>
                            <th>Aplicação</th>
                            <th>Erro</th>
                            <th>Time</th>
                            <th>Tarefas</th>
                            <th>Ordem</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let etapa of etapaData">
                            <td><input type='checkbox' id="etapa{{etapa.id}}" [checked]="etapa.checked" class="valign-wrapper"><label
                                    class="valign-wrapper" for="etapa{{etapa.id}}"></label></td>
                            <td>{{etapa.aplicacao.nome}}</td>
                            <td>{{etapa.erro.nome}}</td>
                            <td>{{etapa.perfil.nome}}</td>
                            <div *ngFor="let tarefa of etapa.tarefas">{{tarefa.nome}}</div>
                            <td><label for="ordem"></label>
                                <input placeholder="Ordem da etapa no Workflow" type="text" class="form-control" id="ordem{{etapa.id}}" required
                                    [(ngModel)]="etapa.ordem" name="etapa.ordem"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="input-field">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit<i
                            class="material-icons right">send</i></button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" [hidden]="!submitted">
                <h4>Registro submetido com sucesso!</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the problem is that you have 3 `input` elements with the same `name`. Can you try to change it to `name="etapa.ordem{{ etapa.id }}"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code should be:

```
<input placeholder="Ordem da etapa no Workflow" type="text" class="form-control" id="ordem{{etapa.id}}" required value="{{ etapa.ordem }}" name="etapa.ordem">
```

Comment: beanic, I guess that the downvoter expected you to explain what is the solution..

Comment: Mosh Feu the solution is value="{{ etapa.ordem }}". Thank you for -1 vote

Answer (score 0):

According to docs

> Each input element has a name property that is required by Angular
>   forms to register the control with the form.
>   [Angular Doc](https://angular.io/guide/forms)

I think the name property is all the same in all inputs in the for loop. Can you please check it?